# View difference percentage for binary file

Tags: diff, binaryfiles, plasticscm

When PlasticSCM detects a move, it shows similarity% in the Pending Changes window. Is there a way to show this % metric, either in the GUI or from the command line, for binary files that are detected as having been changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid the % of similarity is only available for the "local moved" files.

It would be a nice thing to have so I encourage you to add this to the Plastic SCM uservoice web => [UserVoice](https://plasticscm.uservoice.com/forums/15467-general).